# ExecutorService shutdown method behave differently why?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, blockingqueue

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ArrayBlockingQUeueExampe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(2);

        Runnable r = () -> {
            int i = 0;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Added : "+i);
                    q.put(i++);
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Runnable r2 = () -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Integer take = q.take();
                    System.out.println("Taken : "+take);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        ExecutorService  service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        service.submit(r);
        service.submit(r2);
        service.shutdown();
    }
}
```

I am calling `shutdown()` at the end code , so executor service must immediately shutdown , no previously submitted tasks should execute , but when i ran this code , it is continuously running  why ?

Answer (score 0):

The [javadocs for `shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) indicate that an "orderly" shutdown is initiated:

> …in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.

So your infinite tasks are executing, and no new tasks will be accepted (you don't offer any new ones anyway).

Conversely, [`shutdownNow()` says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()):

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.
> This method does not wait for actively executing tasks to terminate. Use [`awaitTermination`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) to do that.

Answer (score 0):

shutdown() is used for graceful shutdown meaning that it will only exit until all submitted tasks finish.  shutdownNow() will interrupt the current all actively executing tasks and shut down.  However, I notice in your code, you are catching InterruptedException without exiting out the loop, so your program will continue running after the interrupt.

If you want to terminate immediately, you need to change two places:

1. use shutdownNow
2. break out of the loop when catching the InterruptedException